# How can I make my node.js app accessible public?

Tags: node.js, nginx

Today I made my raspberry pi zero w server. Installed node, pm2, git, nginx. etc, everything worked fine until I tried to make app accessible publically by nginx.

Whenever I try to use my domain or public IP I get into my operator login page:
[picture of login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfbA.png)

It's my first app in node, so I don't even know if my nginx is well-configured.
[nginx config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0q4.png) where: 
server_name is my public ipv4,
proxy_pass is raspberrypi local ip with port that node.js app is listening on.

And also you might find it useful: [result of sudo netstat -an | grep LISTEN |grep :80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWrEV.png)

What I tried:
Setup custom domain with DNS record, it sends me back to [login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfbA.png)
restart nginx configs plenty of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address you are using is the Internet-facing IP address of your router / modem. It is not the IP address of the computer running nginx (which probably doesn't have an Internet-facing IP address).

You might be able to configure your router to forward requests for a given port to the internal IP address of the computer running nginx on your LAN.

You might be better off using third-party hosting rather than exposing computers inside your network to the Internet.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for your answer, that really helped me out. But why should I use third-party hosting? Is exposing computers inside my network making them any vunerable? I got firewall on. And if I would, could you reccomend me any third-party hosting? I heard about digitalocean, would you reccomend it?

Comment: If your code is exploitable, then that could be leveraged so that an attacker can make network requests to any computer on your LAN (which is behind the router's firewall). I wouldn't recommend any particular hosting service and have no experience with digitalocean.